# Fiddler with JMeter when JMeter is using a proxy

Tags: jmeter, fiddler

I am using JMeter with an authenticated proxy e.g.

```
jmeter -H 10.12.12.5 -P 1080 -u myuser -a password
```

In Fiddler I've done a Rules->Customize as below where xxxxxxxxxx is the base64 encoding of my username:password:

```
    if (!oSession.isHTTPS) 
    {
        oSession.oRequest["Proxy-Authorization"] = "Basic xxxxxxxxxx";
    }
```

Also under Tools->Options-Gateway I've set Manual Proxy and entered the proxies as:

```
http=10.12.12.5;https=10.12.12.5
```

However when I playback the traffic from JMeter Fiddler is not picking it up.

Comment: If fiddler is not capturing requests, proxy configurations are not working. Are any of the requests failing in JMeter. How does `View Results Tree` look like?
To debug, can you try setting proxy in HTTP Sampler --> Advanced tab --> Proxy Server

Comment: Thanks for your reply. JMeter is working fine. No errors at all. It's just I can't get the traffic to go through fiddler.

Comment: @ratsstack You may close the question with your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man, you pointed both JMeter and Fiddler to use some 3rd-party proxy, there is no any connectivity between them, if you want to see JMeter's traffic in Fiddler - you need to:

1. Configure Fiddler to use the 3rd-party proxy
2. Configure JMeter to use Fiddler as the proxy something like:

   - In Fiddler Tools->Options-Gateway `http=10.12.12.5;https=10.12.12.5`
   - In [Fiddler Tools-> Options - Connections - Fiddler listens on port](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler-everywhere/user-guide/settings/connections) - check the value, the default is `8888`
   - Run JMeter to use Fiddler as the proxy like:

     ```
     jmeter -H localhost -P 8888
     ```
   - You might need to import Fiddler's certificate into JMeter or vice versa
3. And last but not the least, you can use JMeter's [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager/) to send this Proxy-Authorization header

   [image]

More information: [Configure Fiddler as Reverse Proxy](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/usefiddlerasreverseproxy)